# How to run pip in non-interactive mode?

Tags: linux, shell, python, pip

Most of tools I'm using have some mode (often ON by default) where they ask me zero questions while running the command. apt-get is an example close to pip. There's -y option which makes it non-interactive. Is there any such option for pip? If there's no such option how to wrap it into some script which will achieve what I want. For example I would like to run something like:

```
pipyes install mypackage
```

Currently I'm doing this, but would like to wrap it into script:

```
yes | pip install mypackage
```

Is it "correct" way to achieve pip non-interactive mode.

Answer (score 32):

There is a [--yes option](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_uninstall/?highlight=#cmdoption-y) specifically for the uninstall command. Calling

```
pip uninstall --yes <some-package>
```

uninstalls the package without asking for confirmation.

For installing, piping in the yes command [still seems to be the way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8400396/2626627).

Another approach that might be overkill depending on your use case is using a dedicated tool. This is definitely the way to go, if one struggles with automatic installation and configuration on a regular basis. As an example: SaltStacks [state system](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/index.html#states) has [tons of ways to automate interaction with pip](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.pip_state.html#module-salt.states.pip_state). This is not only for orchestrating server farms, but can be used locally as well by running [salt-call](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/cli/salt-call.html) directly. See the introduction about running salt [masterless](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/quickstart.html#salt-call).

Answer (score 15):

With recent versions of setuptools (pip version >= 20.2), you can use:

```
pip install --no-input ...
```

… which will disable prompting user for private repo credentials.

Comment: Yes is old post, but for any scavengers passing by, the correct option (that worked for me in pip version 20.0.2) is `--no-input`

Answer (score 1):

I'm far from a python/pip expert, but I have used it for various purposes for several years and have yet to encounter a straight forward use of pip install that is interactive.  It does have extensive options for less straight forward case (alternate package indices, caching, dev mode, etc,).  If you have a specific install case that requires some interaction, my guess is you could automate it by providing the correct combination of specialized options, documented [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#options).

Uninstall is the case I'm much more used to requiring interaction (includes an explicit confirmation to remove modules), and it does in fact support the standard [--yes flag](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_uninstall.html#options) you refer to in the question.